# Jquery tab and header conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My about page have three jquery tabs(I have used easy tab plugin). When I refresh the page with second tab the header portion is not showing up. and when I click the tab in a new browser tab also the header is not showing up. How can I solve this?? (Just click the second tab and refresh the page)

here my content

```
<div id="tab-container" class='tab-container'>
  <ul class='etabs'>
    <li class='tab'>
      <a href="#tabs1-html">
        HTML Markup
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class='tab'>
      <a href="#tabs1-js">
        Required JS
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class='tab'>
      <a href="#tabs1-css">
        Example CSS
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class='panel-container'>
    <div id="tabs1-html">
      <h2>
        HTML Markup for these tabs
      </h2>



      <p>
        Dummy content
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs1-js">
      <h2>
        JS for these tabs
      </h2>

      <p>
        dummy content 2
      </p>




    </div>
    <div id="tabs1-css">
      <h2>
        CSS Styles for these tabs
      </h2>

      <p>
        dummy content 3
      </p>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here my Js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function() {
      $('#tab-container').easytabs();
    });
</script>
```

[javascript link1](http://sesameindia.net/testing/flutura/js/jquery.easytabs.js)

[javascript link 2](http://sesameindia.net/testing/flutura/js/jquery.hashchange.min.js)

Here my page link

[Live page](http://sesameindia.net/testing/flutura/about_us_trial2.php)

Answer (score 0):

Your code JS :

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#tab-container').easytabs();
});
```

is not executed.

If you execute it in the console, you will see your tabs correctly displayed.
Where have you put this code ?

Comment: just above the </head> tag. Sorry I am working on that page I have updated the page. But still the same issue showing up.

Comment: I think it may be something to do with the hashchange plugin you're using.  Try disabling that and see what happens

Comment: But it is working fine in Easy tab plugin site. os.alfajango.com/easytabs